# Blender changing magazine covers!

Tags: texturing

I am new to Blender. I recieved project done in Blender and i have to reassign pages to magazine and all other materials. How i do that?

Tnx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment what we see in the 3D view is an *Instance* of the collection called *Magazine*. In the *Outliner*, activate *Magazine* and you'll see the original in the 3D view. Select the pages the one after the other, check their material in the *Shader Editor* and in the *Image Texture* node, close the current image and load the image that is supposed to be displayed by this page:

[image]

The 4 viewport shading modes:

[image]

If you want to move the pages a bit, first disable the *Snap* tool, then move and keyframe the new location:

[image]

Comment: Tnx. I am closer now, but i replaced textures in first page, but there are no texture on my main model. Its blank everything.

Comment: I only see textures if i render image. Is there a way i can see changes in real time?

Comment: have you switch to Material Preview or Render Preview mode? Changing the image works for me

Comment: Ok. Where i can find this Material Preview or Render preview?  Tnx

Comment: take a look at my edit  ;)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Now the last problem i see. There are some pages interference at the begining. How can i repair that?

Comment: You need to move the page a bit, see my edit

Comment: Woow. Tnx. And now really last thing: If i go render-render animation it renders only one frame. How i export all animation? Tnx

Comment: In the Outliner > Output, choose the destination folder, then go into the Render panel (top left) > Render Animation.

Comment: Thank you for all your time. You saved me a lot. Tnx anf god bless you.

Comment: Oh man. I render all animation and it shows in Blender rendered image in realtime, but when i open exr file in After effects everything is black. What is wrong?

Comment: can you open them with an image editor? You could open them in the viedo sequencer of Blender itself (Shit A)

Comment: I can open them in Premier or After effects, but there is only black. Can you try to render project and see if it is ok? Tnx

Comment: Edit: So it actually works fine with the current settings, I can open in Krita, I just need to enable transparency. So now it has to do with Premiere or After Effects, not Blender, you need to find the option that will allow transparency (you can find some answers on this topic). Or try PNG / RGBA

Comment: Tnx. I changed output to Tga and now it shows image. Tnx for help

Comment: it should be fixable for OpenEXR, but I don't know Premiere or AE

Comment: I am trying to replace textures in shader editor. I am searching how to import all textures at once or drag them into node and replace old one in shading tab. Is there an easy way to just pick and throw new texture to node. If i do that Blender creates new node? Tnx

Comment: you can drag and drop an image from the File Browser window into the Shader Editor window if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but then it creates new node and you have to reconnect nodes. Is there a way to just throw image from file browser on existing node and replace old texture?

Comment: I don't know that, maybe ask a new question?